# Node.js application running errors

Tags: node.js, deployment, tcp, unhandled-exception, issue-tracking

On my local PC this application runs correctly without any errors. But when I run it on my server it shows those errors. :-(

```
(node:3100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:618:25)
(node:3100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3100) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Can you show the code? It could be that you're not composing the asynchronous call correctly; it could be a version difference... lots of things, but people here will be able to help you better if you show the code that's failing.

Comment: It's a big project with more files. I don't know which file actually has this issue. Previously it works correctly.

Comment: Maybe the port is used?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using another (older) version of nodejs on your local pc as on the server. You should consider handling any error that might be thrown from the promise, since it can kill the whole process in future versions of node.

I assume there is no listener for the 'error' but I can tell more if you can reveal the code.

Comment: My local pc and server has same node version(v8.11.4)